# Syntax for a for loop in ruby

Tags: ruby, syntax

How do I do this type of for loop in Ruby?

```
for(int i=0; i<array.length; i++) {

}
```

Comment: @johannes Reading a book is a good idea, but preferably not one about Ruby 1.6!

Comment: Don't forget to take a look at some useful methods in [ruby-doc: Enumerable module](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Enumerable.html).

Answer (score 121, accepted):

```
array.each do |element|
  element.do_stuff
end
```

or

```
for element in array do
  element.do_stuff
end
```

If you need index, you can use this:

```
array.each_with_index do |element,index|
  element.do_stuff(index)
end
```

Comment: i was looking specifically for indexing in a loop, none of these solutions make it immediately obvious how to do that. the op betrayed his intentions with array.length in the code...

Comment: Read my answer carefully. There's a looping solution with indexing included.

Comment: Often times, `each` is great. But sometimes I just want a goddamn traditional for loop. Sometimes the "Ruby way" can be just plain annoying.

Comment: how do i manually set index in ruby so i can write a sort myself

Comment: what if i want to skip next two iterations

Comment: @MuhammadUmer did you find a way to skip a couple of interactions, after 5 years(literally)?

Comment: in regular for loop you can always use `next`, which is equivalent to `continue` from JS.

Answer (score 80):

```
limit = array.length;
for counter in 0..limit
 --- make some actions ---
end
```

---

the other way to do that is the following

```
3.times do |n|
  puts n;
end
```

thats will print 0, 1, 2, so could be used like array iterator also

Think that variant better fit to the author's needs

Answer (score 34):

I keep hitting this as a top link for google "ruby for loop", so I wanted to add a solution for loops where the step wasn't simply '1'.  For these cases, you can use the 'step' method that exists on Numerics and Date objects.  I think this is a close approximation for a 'for' loop.

```
start = Date.new(2013,06,30)
stop = Date.new(2011,06,30)
# step back in time over two years, one week at a time
start.step(stop, -7).each do |d| 
    puts d
end
```

Answer (score 23):

The equivalence would be

```
for i in (0...array.size)
end
```

or

```
(0...array.size).each do |i|
end
```

or

```
i = 0
while i < array.size do
   array[i]
   i = i + 1 # where you may freely set i to any value
end
```

Answer (score 17):

```
array.each_index do |i|
  ...
end
```

It's not very Rubyish, but it's the best way to do the for loop from question in Ruby

Comment: This is brilliant. It's true that the answer is not `each` but rather `each_index`. +1

Answer (score 14):

To iterate a loop a fixed number of times, try:

```
n.times do
  #Something to be done n times
end
```

Answer (score 11):

If you **don't need to access your array**, (just a simple for loop) you can use [upto](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Integer.html#method-i-upto) or each :

**Upto:**

```
2.upto(4) {|i| puts i}
2
3
4
```

**Each:**

```
(2..4).each {|i| puts i}
2
3
4
```

Answer (score 8):

What? From 2010 and nobody mentioned Ruby has a fine for /in loop (it's just nobody uses it):

```
ar = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
for item in ar
  puts item
end
```

Comment: One advantage of *.each... do* is that the block temporary falls out of scope at the end of the loop, whereas *for...in* leaves the temporary in scope.

Answer (score 4):

```
['foo', 'bar', 'baz'].each_with_index {|j, i| puts "#{i} #{j}"}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ruby's enumeration loop syntax is different:

```
collection.each do |item|
...
end
```

This reads as "a call to the 'each' method of the array object instance 'collection' that takes block with 'blockargument' as argument".  The block syntax in Ruby is 'do ... end' or '{ ... }' for single line statements.

The block argument '|item|' is optional but if provided, the first argument automatically represents  the looped enumerated item.