# Loop through Array to display # of characters

Tags: arrays, ruby, loops

Given an Array with some words in it, loop through the Array to display the number of characters in each word.

```
friends = ["Dan", "Mindy", "Suhasini", "Ryan"]
```

Comment: Smells like homework. Care to share the loop you've built?

Comment: Is there a way to flag such question as "asking to solve homework while showing no effort at all" ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Syntax for a for loop in ruby](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2032875/syntax-for-a-for-loop-in-ruby)

Comment: Its actually for an admission question where we were to get as far as we could on our own, and then use any resources we could find for help.  Im sorry if this is not the place for those types of questions.  Im very new at this.

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking to return an array with length displayed, the following would work:

```
friends = ["Dan", "Mindy", "Suhasini", "Ryan"]
p friends.map { |friend| friend.length }
```

Comment: ...which you could write `p friends.map(&:length)`.

Answer (score 1):

You can display the number of characters using an array as following.

```
friends = ["Dan", "Mindy", "Suhasini", "Ryan"]
def count_char(friends)
    count = 0
    friends.each do |word|
        count = word.length
        puts "'#{word}' has #{count} character(s)"
    end
end

count_char(friends)
=>
'Dan' has 3 character(s)
'Mindy' has 5 character(s)
'Suhasini' has 8 character(s)
'Ryan' has 4 character(s)
```

For more array reference : http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html