# Adding to arrays based on names of elements in another array

Tags: arrays, ruby

Couldn't find a less confusing title but here is the pseudo-code:

```
for all video['tags'][i] in video['tags'][3..-1]
  topic = video['tags'][i]
  topic_array += video['id']
end
```

Let's say there are 2 elements in the video['tags'][3..-1]:

```
video['tags'][3..-1] # => ["Health", "Politics"]
video['id']          # => 35
```

I want to add the integer 35 to two different arrays named Health and Politics. Those arrays may or may not exist beforehand.

End result example:

```
Health # => [21, 25, 35]
Politics # => [35]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using multiple arrays to store ids for each tag, i would use one hash in which each key is a tag and its value is the array of ids, for example:

```
tags = { "Health" => [21, 25] }
```

With that in place, you could solve your problem with something like this:

```
video["tags"][3..-1].each do |tag|
  tags.key?(tag) ? tags[tag] << video["id"] : tags[tag] = [video["id"]]
end
```

Check for `tags` contents:

```
tags
#=> {"Health"=>[21, 25, 35], "Politics"=>[35]}
```

To get the ids, you simply fetch/read the key (i.e tag) you want from `tags` hash, for example:

```
tags["Health"]
#=> [21, 25, 35]
```

Comment: Thanks, but is my pseudo-code not realizable in Ruby?

Comment: @Emre You can use a `for` loop (check [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2032875/syntax-for-a-for-loop-in-ruby)), although its more idiomatic to use `each`; but you can't dynamically create variables, that's why another data structure (i.e `Hash`) is recommended.