# How to do loop in ruby

Tags: ruby, loops

I need help putting this question in a loop:

```
puts "Rate the requirements and quality on a scale from 1-10 points."
x = gets.chomp.to_f
raq = 3318.6 *  1.5066**x 
puts "This will cost " + raq.to_s + "kr."
```

If the user answers anything other than 1 through 10, they must be asked the question again. I have many questions in a row, so I would appreciate not having the whole program restart but just the single question.

Comment: Have you read on loops in ruby? If not, go read that. If yes, what specific problems are you encountering?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev

This is what i tried, but i keep asking the questions no matter what i wrote.

while x!=(1..10).to_s
  puts "Rate the requirements and quality on a scale from 1-10 points."
  x = gets.chomp.to_f
  
end

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Syntax for a for loop in ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2032875/syntax-for-a-for-loop-in-ruby)

Comment: @MadsEnoch please edit your question instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
x = nil

until (1..10).include? x
  puts "Rate the requirements and quality on a scale from 1-10 points."
  x = gets.to_f
end

raq = 3318.6*1.5066**x 

puts "This will cost #{raq}kr."
```

(Personally, I'd try to use something a little more descriptive than `x` :) )

Comment: You should remove the redundant `chomp`. Also, better to use string interpolation and get rid of `to_s` on the last line.

Comment: Fair enough - I just added the `until` loop in there and used the rest of the code from the question. Makes sense to have it nice and clean though. Will edit @sawa

Comment: Ofcourse, until. Totally forgot that existed, thank you!